# Extract year from datetime format

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm doing my final year project using asp.net as front end and SQL Server 2005 as back end

My question is: I want extract only the year from datetime format. And use the year to filter data

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mr. Wheats answer. Just adding a few more possibilities

**C#**

```
a) int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

b) Given a date

int year = Convert.ToDateTime("12/28/2010").Year;
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim year As Int32
year = DateTime.Now.Year
```

**Sql Server 2005**

***Using DATENAME***

a) `select [year] = DATENAME(yy,getdate())`

b) From a given date  `select [year] = DATENAME(yy,'12/31/2010')`

**Using DATEPART**

a) `select [year] = DATEPART(yy,getdate())`

b) From a given date `select [year] = DATEPART(yy,'12/31/2010')`

**Using Year Function(Added after Marc's comment)**

```
select [year] = YEAR (getdate())
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use YEAR(date) in T-SQL, since it's deterministic - DATEPART is **not** determistic, so you can't use it e.g. in a stored function or a field computation

Answer (score 3):

In C#:

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

If you mean at the T-SQL level:

```
DATEPART ("yyyy", date)
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use YEAR(date), since it's deterministic